# Issue with importing Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, data-visualization

When I try to import seaborn the import give me the below error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 import seaborn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

I have tried the below steps to install:

1. `pip install seaborn`
2. `python -m pip install seaborn`
3. `!conda install seaborn`
4. `%%bash pip install seaborn`
5. `pip3 install seaborn`
6. `conda install seaborn`
7. `sudo pip install utils` ...and then install seaborn again
8. `pip uninstall scipy` and then install scipy package again.

These are the solutions I found, I closed iTerm and started it again and none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Python and pip installed on your computer. Reinstall it if you have it. Try `pip install seaborn`. Also, make sure you are installing it in the same directory as where you are working. If that issue still persists, there must be a problem with your shell or computer.

PS:
If you are using Juypter Notebook do in a cell:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install seaborn
```

Comment: yes, i have those installed. i also did try the command you have given. still nothing

Comment: Look at my post script (PS).